# PDFMiner does not parse more than 1 page

Tags: python, pypdf, pdfminer

I'm using PDFMiner6 with Python 3.5. It's far better than PyPDF2 (slower, but more accurate and doesn't spit out a bunch of letters that are not separated by spaces). I tried to parse this document:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2963791/
(You can download the PDF free from the NIH website).

I used this code (it's part of a larger spider, but the rest of the code is not relevant to this question):

```
import io
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

class PDFMiner6(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def PdfFileReader(self, fp):
        text = []
        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
        retstr = io.StringIO()
        codec = 'utf-8'
        laparams = LAParams()
        device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
        password = ""
        maxpages = 0
        caching = True
        pagenos = set()

        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True): 
            interpreter.process_page(page)
            output = retstr.getvalue()
            text.append(output)

        fp.close()
        device.close()
        retstr.close()
        return text
```

It parses the first page perfectly, then stops. The rest of the document is not parsed.

I tested the same document using PyPDF2, it parses the entire document but outputs garbage without any spaces (hence I switched over to PDFMiner6). So I'm sure that it's not that the entire document is not being read but something wrong with the code that's parsing it. What is wrong?

**EDIT:** I went ahead and tested it on different PDF files with varying results - it parses some completely, whereas others, it stops at the first page. This is frustrating, as PDFMiner6 is a better parser compared to PyPDF2.

Could anybody help?

Comment: Your code runs well for me using Python 3.7. I validated the result by searching string "Page 10" in the result

Comment: Did you change any of the settings? I keep getting only the first page of the PDF, the program stops and doesn't parse the rest of the document. I'm using Python 3.5.5 with Anaconda...

Comment: I didn't change anything. I just instantiate the class & call the method `PDFMiner6().PdfFileReader(fpin)` then loop through the result to write it to text file. This is the result txt file https://file.io/C23LXV. I installed `pdfminer.six==20170720` using `pip`

Comment: No, I think you only got the first page - like me. The PDF that I linked only has 8 pages, not 10. So, I'm not sure how you got "Page 10"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the pdf is being opened by a pdf viewer and not a web browser. I had the same issue and this is how I fixed it.

It looks like pdfminer will view a pdf that is being opened by a web browser as one page. So you need to make sure that it is being opened by a pdf viewer so pdfminer recognizes that there are more than 1 page on the pdf.